# Include custom file on android build

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a mobile app with Unity. I generate levels from MIDI files. How can I include those MIDI files in the android build? I can't find it in the APK. I need a file path for those MIDI files.

Comment: You can add those files in a folder called ```StreamingAsset``` and load it using ```UnityWebRequest``` or use ```Resource``` and use ```Resource.Load()``` to load.

Comment: None of these folders are created by Unity you have to create by your self

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm working on this, but the issue is the library which handles midi files for me uses path to read it. I can find the files in the APK, but Unity throws a DirectoryNotFoundException.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are including your midi files in the `StreamingAssets` folder:

On Android, files in `StreamingAssets` are compressed. You need to use the `UnityWebRequest` class to get them out.

From the [manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-streamingAssetsPath.html):

> It is not possible to access the StreamingAssets folder on WebGL and
> Android platforms. No file access is available on WebGL. Android uses
> a compressed .apk file. These platforms return a URL. Use the
> UnityWebRequest class to access the Assets.

If your midi library can't read them like that, load them via `UnityWebRequest` and save them to another path (like `Application.PersistentDataPath`) so you can give a real file path to the library for loading.

Comment: Thank you very much, this works fine. I can access the midi file and when I copy to the ```Application.PersistentDataPath``` the library also can handle it.